# Python Pillow .ico convert to .gif

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I used python pillow library because i need to convert .ico to .gif

So i used Pillow 6.1.0 ver with Python 3.7.0
I do the following:

```py
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("a.ico")
im.show()

im.save("a.gif")
```

.ico file has transparent background

But im.show() loaded Image is black background 
So finally i got black background .gif file

**I want to know how i get transparent .gif conversion files!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `im.show()` loaded Image is black background

It is because `Image.show()`  converts the image to `.bmp` (bitmap) before displaying it. And **Bitmap** in `PIL` doesn't supports Alpha (variable Transparency/Opacity). Therefore, the alpha data in your `.ico` image gets lost when you try to display the image using `Image.show()`.

**Solution:-** Don't view image containing alpha values using `Image.show()`, instead save the image and then view it *(via some Image processing package like **photoshop** etc, or using your OS's builtin image viewer like **Photos** in Windows 10*).

> I want to know how i get transparent `.gif` conversion files!

`.gif` (graphical interchange format) does not support Alpha channel. So, it is not possible for you to convert `.ico` file into a `.gif` while retaining the transparent regions. Therefore, it is not advised to save an image having Alpha channel to a `.gif`, because it ends up having artifacts and would degrade the quality of the original image.

**Solution:-** I would suggest you to choose a format like `.png` or `.jp2`, which supports alpha channel. They support a large range of colors too (as opposed to a **GIF**, which supports only 256 discrete colors (*8 bit palette*)).

Comment: Thanks to replying